# Dynamic find-replace part of string

Tags: php, regex

I want to get rid of the second part of a PHP variable which has an fixed format but the numbers are always different. So I cannot use a simple str_replace. I am looking for an regular expression solution to fix this.

> $string = "First example from this part 10 t/m 16 it has to be removed";
>
> $string = "Second example from this part 12 t/m 22 it has to be removed";

Have to become:

> $string = "First example";
>
> $string = "Second example";

Comment: If you don't show us your efforts on solving it, this will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: So you always want the two first words? Why only regex solution? There are so many other solutions that is capable to do this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and use a whitespace as the delimiter to get the first 2 words:

```
$strings = [
    "First example from this part 10 t/m 16 it has to be removed",
    "Second example from this part 12 t/m 22 it has to be removed"
];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $parts = explode(" ", $string);
    echo implode(" ", [$parts[0], $parts[1]]);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kmMRk)

If you want to use a regex you might use:

[`^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/oXEXo3/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode, implode and array_slice.
This is much faster and less memory hungry than regex.
Explode creates an array of the string delimited on space.
Array_slice (in this case) takes the two first items of the array.
Implode creates a string from an array (array_slice two items) and adds a space in between.

```
$string = "First example from this part 10 t/m 16 it has to be removed";
echo implode(" ", array_slice(explode(" ", $string), 0,2)); // First example
echo "\n";

$string = "Second example from this part 12 t/m 22 it has to be removed";
echo implode(" ", array_slice(explode(" ", $string), 0,2)); // Second example
```

https://3v4l.org/efX1t

---

If you insist on regex this will do the trick.

```
$re = '/(.*?\s.*?\s)/';
$str = 'First example from this part 10 t/m 16 it has to be removed';

preg_match($re, $str, $match);

echo $match[1]; // First example
```

https://3v4l.org/0efTq

The pattern looks for any charachters, a space, any characters and a space again.